# import script wrong order, function not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vuejs component (`map.vue`) like this:

```
<script> 
import '../../assets/js/map.js' 

export default {
    name: 'home',
    data () {
        return {
            init_data: {},
        }
    },
    created: function() {
         this.init_data = window.get_init_data(this.view, function(response) {
               document.title = response.body.page_title;
               init_map(some_arguments);
         });
    }
}
</script>
```

map.js:

```
const key = ******;
function init_map(some_args) {
    ...
}
```

Error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: init_map is not
>   defined"

And in fact, inspecting the source code the function it's been called before it's signature.

Note: I don't want to include `map.js` in webpack entries because i only need this script in one component (`map.vue`).

Comment: try `require( '../../assets/js/map.js')`

Comment: Already did @OlegShleif , the problem remains. Thanks

Comment: It would not be difficult to explain how?

Comment: @OlegShleif, to explain how about what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

test.js

```
export function writeHello() {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

*****.vue

```
import {writeHello} from './../test.js';

export default {
    created() {
        writeHello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `export` and `export default`? Both worked

Comment: @HulaHula `export` is where you name a class or function (or multiples) which can then be `imported` by specifying the definition with curly braces as in the above. export default means that if no exact definition is supplied it will automatically return the default when importing. an example might be `import foo from '/path/to/bar'` where `foo` becomes the default export.